# Display HTML content for each button click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JS code:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#new-item');
const serviceline = document.querySelector('#service-line');


for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let output = ''
    output += `<p>hello</p>`;
    console.log(output)
    serviceline.innerHTML = output;
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="service-line">
</div>
<button type="button" id="new-item" class="btn">Add New Item</button>
```

And I want to display data in "output" multiple times for each time the button is clicked on. If I console.log the output I get the correct result. I want the HTML display to display a new line with 'hello' by each time the button is clicked on.

Comment: I think the functions name `innerhtml` is mispelled. If you don't write the method correct, the browser does nothing. The correct spelling is  `.innerHTML`.

Comment: fixed it now, still the same issue

Comment: `HTMLNode.innerHTML` is not a function, but an attribute !!!

Comment: so i have to remove innerHTML and use a function instead?

Comment: No, you haven't.

Comment: Why do you use a for loop?

Comment: why do you use a for loop? if you are planning to make multiple buttons with the same `id`, its better to use `class` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a plus in serviceline.innerHTML += output;
Currently when you click the button it overrides the serviceline. + will add the new value with the past value.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#new-item');
const serviceline = document.querySelector('#service-line');


for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let output = ''
    output = `<p>hello</p>`;
    console.log(output)
    serviceline.innerHTML += output;
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="service-line">
</div>
<button type="button" id="new-item" class="btn">Add New Item</button>
```

Comment: Just a pointer, but as there is only ever one element with a given `id` you don't need to iterate over `items` with a loop; if you use `document.querySelector('#new-item').addEventListener('click', (event) => {...});` it should work work perfectly well

Comment: dunno why he used a for loop maybe he will add more buttons with same id in the future.

Comment: thanks, fixed it now and removed the for loop. New to Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why do you do this ?

```js
let output = ''
output += `<p>hello</p>`;
```

You create an empty string and add `<p>hello</p>` to it. That does not make sense, as

```js
let output = `<p>hello</p>`;
```

does exactly the same. But that's not the problem, theproblem here is that you are *overwriting* `serviveline`'s text, instead of *appending* to it. You forgot that little plus sign before the equal sign in `serviceline.innerHTML = output`. Following the working and tidied code:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#new-item');
const serviceline = document.querySelector('#service-line');


for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let output = `<p>hello</p>`;
    console.log(output)
    serviceline.innerHTML += output;
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="service-line">
</div>
<button type="button" id="new-item" class="btn">Add New Item</button>
```